# Rails/Rspec: undefined method `temp_val' for #<GeneralClass:0x00007fd1000ad03>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-6

I am getting this error in rspec.
These are the requireed files

```
# app/models/general_class.rb

class GeneralClass < ApplicationRecord
  validates_with CustomValidator
  validates_with CustomValidator, if: Proc.new { |obj| obj.temp_val.present? }
  validates_presence_of :temp_val_expiry, if: Proc.new { |obj| obj.temp_val.present? }
```

```
# in db/schema.rb

create_table "general_class" do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "field1"
    t.text "field2"
    t.text "temp_val"
    t.datetime "temp_val_expiry"
  end
```

```
# spec/models/general_class.rb

  describe '#test' do
    it 'description' do
      gs = GeneralClass.create(field: "dummy", field2: "value")
      gs.temp_val = 'new_val_temp'
      gs.temp_val_expiry = 1.day.after
      gs.save!
    end
  end
```

When I run the above spec, I am getting this

```
     Failure/Error: validates_with CustomValidator, if: Proc.new { |obj| obj.temp_val.present? }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `temp_val' for #< GeneralClass:0x00007fb8eb95ce40>
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Is `temp_val` newly added column? if yes then you might need to run `rails db:test:prepare` to rebuilt the test db

Comment: You can write a method(something like `has_temp_value?`) that checks the presence of the `temp_val` field and keep a debugger in that and see what is happening-
`validates_with CustomValidator, if: :has_temp_value? }`

Comment: @SampatBadhe Yes it is a new column for which I have already added a new migration file. `rails db:test:prepare` is giving me errors, not sure why.
@SachinSingh I am getting values for `field1` and `field2` but getting `nil` for `temp_val`

Comment: @VaibhavGupta what error you are getting? Could you please share the error details?

Comment: Thank you all of you for helping me with this. Turns out that the object was not getting saved in the test db at all. All the fields were `nil` except `field1` and `field2`. Now I am using `FactoryBot` and this is no longer a problem. If anyone else facing this issue. Create objects using `FactoryBot`